# NPM start serving compiled Javascript as download

Tags: node.js, npm

So I've compiled all my HTML & JS into one JS file using HTML2JS. I want to display the website created for testing purposes but when I use NPM start it doesn't display any content and when visiting the URL automatically downloads the JS file on to my computer. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to return an html file from your server to the browser, in which you can include a `<script>` tag pointing to your unique js file.